# Estimate error using Taylor Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was told to use Taylor Series to find the error of this but I am not confident in doing this.

Estimate the error in approximating $\cos x$ by $1-(x^2/2)$ on the interval $[-0.5, 0.5]$.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lagrange error bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_error_bound#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) states that the gap between $f(x)$ and its Taylor expansion in $x_0$ of order $k$ is
$$
R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}\big(\xi(x)\big)}{(k+1)!} (x-x_0)^{k+1} 
$$
where $\xi(x)$ is a point lying in the interval $[x_0,x]$ or $[x,x_0]$ (depending whether $x_0\leq x$ or $x_0\geq x$). In your case,
$$
1-\frac{x^2}2
$$
is the 3rd order approximation of $\cos x$ in $x_0=0$ (since $\cos'''(0)=\sin(0)=0$), so
$$
R_3(x)
~=~
\cos x - \left(1 - \frac{x^2}2\right)
~=~
\frac{\cos{\big(\xi(x)\big)}}{24}x^4
$$
If $x$ ranges in $[-0.5,0.5]$, then so does $\xi(x)$. Therefore
$$
\max_{[0.5,0.5]}{\big|R_3(x)\big|}
~\leq~
\frac{\max_{[0.5,0.5]}{\big|\cos(x)\big|}}{24}
\max_{[0.5,0.5]}{\big|x^4\big|}
~=~
\frac{1}{24}\cdot\frac{1}{2^4}
~=~
\frac{1}{384}
~\approx~
0.0026\ldots
$$

Comment: How do you know it is the 3rd order approximation of cos x in x0 = 0? and what do you mean by cos'''(0) that gives sin (0) = 0?

Comment: The Taylor expansion of order $k$ of $f$ centered in $x_0$ is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k a_j(x-x_0)^j
$$
where $a_j=\frac{f^{(j)}(x_0)}{j!}$. Therefore, if $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ then the $n$-th coefficient is null. In your case, the 3rd derivative of $\cos x$ is $\cos'''(x)=\sin x$, which evaluated in $x_0=0$ returns $0$. In fact $\cos x = 1 + 0x - \frac 12 x^2 + 0x^3 +\ldots$. Alternatively you could notice that $\cos x$ is an [even function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function#Even_functions), so all the odd coefficients of the Taylor expansion centered in $0$ are null.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F379145%2Fintegral-remainder-converges-to-0&ei=WCuiUfbpINODqgG-3oGIBA&usg=AFQjCNHa3jPYfeMkGssRaSc6io0g2AAhZg&sig2=zFd9NsMfhfEWTMFPEGWPKA). **Hint:**

$$ 
    |\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\,a_k\,-\,\sum_{k=0}^m\,(-1)^k\,a_k|\le |a_{m+1}|. $$

Comment: I would specify that it works only for $a_k$ being the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\cos x$; furthermore, in this case $m$ must be odd, otherwise $a_{m+1}=0$ and the inequality does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

The taylor development of cos x around 0 is just
$$
1-x^2/2+x^4/24-x^6/720+\dots
$$

When you subtract your given term, you get get an error of magnitude 
$$
O(x^4)
$$